# Why is this IF/ELSE not consistent?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reformat rows that have the string "No Action" in them in column C

I use this:

```
Dim ActionRow as Long


For ActionRow = 2 To 50
    If .Cells(ActionRow, 3).Value = "No Action" Then
        .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Italic = True
        .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Color = 8421504
    End If
Next ActionRow
```

Instead of just targeting rows with "No action" in column C, it targets every row, or tracks it inconsistently. How can I tell it to only find the string "No Action" in column C (3) and then execute the formatting?

Rest of Code:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Main()
      Dim Wb As Workbook
      Dim Data, Last, BU7, Lvl7
      Dim sourcerow As Long, sourcecol As Long, destrow As Long, destcol As Long
      Dim rngDest As Range
      Dim ActionRow As Long


      'Refer to the template
      Set Wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
      'Refer to the destination cell
      Set rngDest = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
      'Read in all data
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_")
        Data = .Range("Ab2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      End With
      Wb.Activate
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      'Process the data
      For sourcerow = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        'Manager changes?
        If Data(sourcerow, 15) <> Last Then
          'Skip the first
          If sourcerow > 1 Then

            'Scroll into the view
            rngDest.Select
            'Save a copy
            Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
              ValidFileName("10.08.18" & " - " & BU7 & " - " & Lvl7 & " - " & Last & ".xlsx")
          End If
          'Clear the employees

          ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AB" & ActiveSheet.Columns.Count + 1).ClearContents
          'Remember this manager

          Last = Data(sourcerow, 15)
          BU7 = Data(sourcerow, 18)
          Lvl7 = Data(sourcerow, 25)

          'Start the next round
          destcol = 0
        End If
        'Write the employee data into the template
            destrow = 0
            For sourcecol = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If sourcecol = 1 Then
                rngDest.Offset(destcol, destrow) = CStr(Format(Data(sourcerow, sourcecol), "000000000"))
                    Else
                    rngDest.Offset(destcol, destrow) = Data(sourcerow, sourcecol)
                End If

                    destrow = destrow + 1
            Next

        'Next column
        destcol = destcol + 1

        Next
                With Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

                    For ActionRow = 2 To 50
                            If .Cells(ActionRow, 3).Value = "No Action" Then
                                .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Italic = True
                                .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Color = 8421504
                            End If
                    Next ActionRow

                .Columns("A:ab").Sort key1:=Range("c2"), _
                order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        .Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "000000000"


      End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: @Scott Craner the edit still causes everything to be italicized and grey, I only want the "No Action" values in column C to do that, everything else normal formatting

Comment: I just made the code more readable by aligning the line properly.  I did not change the code in any way.  It will not change how the code works.  But one note, are you always starting with a fresh canvas, are all the text non italicized and not grey before running the code?

Comment: @ScottCraner I have a raw data file with no formatting, and then it's transferred to a template with a header. Then after it reads the data in, I would like it to find any of the "No Actions" in column C, but not any other rows

Comment: There is not enough here for us to figure out, it should do what you want.  There must be other issues with the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: I'd watch for leading/trailing spaces. Try `If Trim(.Cells(...).Value) = "No Action" Then`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I added the rest of the script

Comment: so much for "minimal"...

Comment: shouldn't `key1:=Range("c2")` be `key1:=.Range("c2")` to ensure you are using the correct key?  Not sure your problem but could be another problem in the future.

Comment: You could also *debug the code yourself* by stepping through it line-by-line in the loop and compare expected versus actual behavoir. You'll probably solve it very easily that way :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, instead of using a For Loop, the code below will AutoFilter Column C with the value "No Action", then it will make Italic and colour every visible row from Column A to AB:

```
With WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells.AutoFilter 'add AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$AB$50").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="No Action"
    .Range("$A$2:$AB$50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Italic = True
    .Range("$A$2:$AB$50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Color = 8421504
    .Cells.AutoFilter 'remove AutoFilter
End With
```

**UPDATE:**

To check for the value "No Action" on Column C before using the AutoFilter, you could do something like below:

```
With WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set FoundNoAction = .Range("C:C").Find(What:="No Action", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundNoAction Is Nothing Then
        .Cells.AutoFilter 'add AutoFilter
        .Range("$A$1:$AB$50").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="No Action"
        .Range("$A$2:$AB$50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Italic = True
        .Range("$A$2:$AB$50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Color = 8421504
        .Cells.AutoFilter 'remove AutoFilter
    End If
End With
```

Comment: is autofiltering going to slow down my script?

Comment: @nicklanta to be completely honest I'm not sure, but I would think that formatting the whole range at once instead of looping through each row would actually speed it up, but I might be wrong here....

Comment: I'll try it in a few minutes, I appreciate the help!

Comment: what if certain sheets don't have any "No Action" values, it causes an error to occur

Comment: @nicklanta I thought the code was for a specific Sheet (ie. Sheet1), but I've now updated my answer to check for the value before filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll work with .findnext like this:

```
With sheets(youractionsheet).Range(“A2:AB” & sheets(youractionsheet).cells(rows.count,3).end(xlup).row)
 Set myaction = .cells.find(what:=“No Action”)

If not myaction is nothing then 
 Do until myaction is nothing
 myaction.font.italic = true
 myaction.font.color = 8421504

 Set myaction = .findnext(myaction)

 Loop
End if

End with
```